# After pushing view controller getting blank page on objective c

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, appdelegate, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to push a view controller from the appdelegate. Its redirecting to the proper view controller but the UI is missing.

**Code**

```
-(void)checkConditionToMoveToPaynoteDetailPage
{
    if([_topViewController isKindOfClass:[TCSPayNoteHomeViewController class]])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:popCurrentPaynoteDetailPage object:self];
        [self performSelector:@selector(moveToPaynoteDetailPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
    }
    else{
        BOOL ctrlIsPresent = NO;
        
        for (id ctrlr in  self.navigationCtrlArray )    //required controlled is in betwwen
        {
            if([ctrlr isKindOfClass:[TCSPayNoteHomeViewController class]])
            {
                ctrlIsPresent = YES;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        if(ctrlIsPresent)  //required controlled is in betwwen
        {
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.navController popToViewController:[self.navigationCtrlArray objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES]; // top is required controller
                [self performSelector:@selector(moveToPaynoteDetailPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
            });
            
        }
        else{
            [self moveToPaynoteDetailPage];
            // rquired controller is not in a stack
        }
    }

}

-(void)moveToPaynoteDetailPage
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [self getTopViewController];
    
    TCSPayNoteHomeViewController *paynoteDetailCtrl= [[TCSPayNoteHomeViewController alloc] init];
   
    TCSPayNote *payNoteData = [[TCSPayNote alloc] init];
    
    payNoteData.payNoteEntryID = [_notifInfo valueForKey:@"id"];
    
    paynoteDetailCtrl.payNoteData = payNoteData;
    

    [viewController.navigationController pushViewController:paynoteDetailCtrl animated:NO];
  
}
```

**View controller**

```
-(UIViewController*)getTopViewController
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *viewController = navController.topViewController;
    return viewController;
}

-(void)getNavigationCtrlArray
{
    self.navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    self.navigationCtrlArray = [self.navController viewControllers];
}
```

I'm trying to push a view controller from the appdelegate. Its redirecting to the proper page but UI's are not loading while pushing.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with TCSPayNoteHomeViewController.  Either it has no content (it's an empty view), or some constraints are wrong, such that an important view is zero-sized and everything else isn't displaying due to that.  Normally a view controller comes out of a storyboard or is initialized with a .xib; is there supposed to be a .xib of the same name?  If there is, maybe that .xib wasn't installed as a resource with the app, and it's not being found.  If the view controller class is creating all its views in code, then the problem is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar somewhere but have a different function for `getTopViewController`. Here is my code.

```
// Find and return top view controller
+ ( UIViewController * ) topViewController
{
    return [fmUiUtil topViewControllerFrom:UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

// Given a starting point, find the best top view controller
+ ( UIViewController * ) topViewControllerFrom:( UIViewController * ) vc
{
    if ( vc.presentedViewController )
    {
        return [fmUiUtil topViewControllerFrom:vc.presentedViewController];
    }
    else if ( [vc isKindOfClass:UISplitViewController.class] )
    {
        UISplitViewController * svc = ( UISplitViewController * ) vc;

        if ( svc.viewControllers.count )
        {
            return [fmUiUtil topViewControllerFrom:svc.viewControllers.lastObject];
        }
        else
        {
            return vc;
        }
    }
    else if ( [vc isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.class] )
    {
        UINavigationController * svc = ( UINavigationController * ) vc;

        if ( svc.viewControllers.count )
        {
            return [fmUiUtil topViewControllerFrom:svc.topViewController];
        }
        else
        {
            return vc;
        }
    }
    else if ( [vc isKindOfClass:UITabBarController.class] )
    {
        UITabBarController * svc = ( UITabBarController * ) vc;

        if ( svc.viewControllers.count )
        {
            return [fmUiUtil topViewControllerFrom:svc.selectedViewController];
        }
        else
        {
            return vc;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return vc;
    }
}
```

Also, in the delegate, I use `[topVC presentViewController ...` and not `[topVC.navigationController pushVC` as you do.